# Check whether a string contains numbers

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, string, validation

I have input values like:

```
string = "devid"
string = "devid123"
string = "devid.123.devid"
```

I need to sort strings that contain `.(number).`, for example `"devid.123.devid"`. How can I separate only strings that consist of `.(numbers).` like `.123.`? Help me find a solution.

In a controller, I have:

```
@person = Person.new
personname = params['personname']
if personname.match("/\d+/")
  @person.person_name = personname
  @person.save()
  result = 'true'
end
```

When I execute this code, I get `"devid123"` and `"devid.123.devid"`.

Comment: So the number must be preceded by a dot?

Comment: So you mean you want to separate string which contains number. right?

Comment: Where is `string` used? I don't see it in your code.

Comment: `match("/\d+/")` (with quotes) won't match any of `"devid123"` or `"devid.123.devid"`. Do you mean `match(/\d+/)` (without quotes)? Anyway, to match a number surrounded by dots, you have to include the dots in your regexp. Try `match(/\.\d+\./)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If its certain that the format of the valid **personname** is always

`<string>.<number>.<string>`

You can try using `:[regex, index]` method for strings in ruby.

https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.1/String.html#method-i-5B-5D

So if

`personname = "devid.123.devid"`

`s[/(.*)(\.\d+\.)(.*)/, 2] = ".123."`

There are three different groups in the regex `(.*)(\.\d+\.)(.*)`.

1. Matches anything
2. Matches a `.<number>.`
3. Matches anything

So based on this regex, the second group should provide you `.<number>.` which, I hope, is what you need.

Tested with Ruby 2.4.1

Comment: thank you so much @Abhishek Sharma.. it is working fine. getting exact output

Comment: Also as @AntarrByrd pointed out, I suggest you to please keep this logic as a validation in your model instead of your controller as string matching is a use case of ActiveRecord validations. Also skinny controller (no presentation/business logic) is a rails best practice, in order to adhere to **Separation of Concerns**.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand this correctly you only want a string where the digits are preceded by `.`. If so you need to modify your regex to be `/\.\d+/`

```
@person = Person.new
personname=params['personname']
if personname.match("/\.\d+/")
  @person.person_name = personname
  @person.save
  result = 'true'
end
```

But this sounds like logic you should be handling in the model, since this is tagged as rails and not plain old ruby

#### controller

```
class PersonController

  def create
    if @person = Person.create(params)
      result = 'true'
    else
       result = 'false'
    end
    # whatever you doing with result
  end
end
```

#### person.rb

```
class Person < ApplicationRecord
  validates :personname, format: { with: /\.\d+\./, message: 'must include digits' }
end
```

You can play with the regex [@ rubular](https://rubular.com/r/YuCNuxoL1DI4Y8)